# Could someone confirm that push r64 should be 50+ro not +rd? Error in Intel doc?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel

The reference for the `PUSH` instruction reproduced below from Intel's docs (Volume 2B) shows the opcode 50 + *rd* for the instruction PUSH *r64*, when it should be 50 + *ro*, as far as I can understand Section 3.1.1.1 in Volume 2A.

Also [online HTML extract](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push) of the `push` entry.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it should be `+ro`.

Comment: @Jester Thanks. I'll use this comment to make another observation about Figure 2.7 in Section 2.2.1.2 of Chapter 2 in Volume 2A, which I think is misleading. I'll try to explain this in my next comment.

Comment: @Jester Figure 2.7 shows the bit REX.B, as if it would add 8 to the value corresponding to the 3 bits in the opcode reg field. But Table 3.1 in Volume 2A doesn't have any entry for the Reg field that is greater than 7. Because of this, it took me hours studying this Table, until I realized that the `Yes` in it, means REX.B = 1 and `None` means REX.B = 0, which seems to be the correct way to interpret how this bit should be used, to determine the register containing the value to be pushed into the stack. Any comments on this?

Comment: Yes, `REX.B` adds `8` to the reg field, so it is in fact correct that the reg field in that table only has values 0-7. To get `r10` you use reg field 2 with `REX.B=1`. See also figures 2-4 through 2-7.

Comment: Of course now I can understand this. But it was very confusing, for me at least, to arrive at this conclusion. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Alexander "None" also covers the case where there's no REX prefix byte at all, which is how you would normally encode an instruction like `push rax`.

Comment: @Alexander: Often it's helpful to look at real machine code and what assemblers actually do.  e.g. assembling `push rax` and `push r10` and looking at the machine code (e.g. `nasm -felf64 -l/dev/stdout foo.asm` to make a listing on the terminal) would have given you some hints, and shown you that REX is only needed at all for a non-zero `.B` field.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for reminding me about the online HTML extract in your edit. I'll start using them in my next question.

Comment: There are similar errors in Intel doc concerning instruction **MOV** and some others, see https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/links.htm#IntelVol2